# How to pass list of arrays within list of object to the Razor view?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of arrays which contains Model. I am passing this list to view but not able to access properties of the Model, only getting description written on indexes of arrays.

This is my Controller :

```
**final1 = list contains model with specific query**            

           var final22 = new List<Movies>();
           var final33 = new Array[acd.Count()];
           for (int i = 0; i < acc.Count(); i++)
            {
                final22 = final1.Where(c => c.Id == acc[i]).ToList();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < acd.Count(); i++)
            {
                final33[i] = final1.Where(c => c.Id == acd[i]).ToArray();
            }
            var viewmodel = new ShowRecommendationGenreViewModel
            {
               Show_data = final33.ToList() };

                return View("ShowRecommendationGenre", viewmodel);
            }
```

This is my View :

```
      @model Project.Models.ViewModels.ShowRecommendationGenreViewModel
        @foreach (var abcc in Model.Show_data)
        {   
           @abcc.GetValue(0)    
        }
```

Output i am getting :

```
     Project.Models.Movies
     Project.Models.Movies
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `@abcc.GetValue(0)` returns a `Movie` which you are trying to display.  By default, classes do not overload the `ToString` method, and use the default `object` implementation, which just displays the type name.
2. You are using an untyped `Array` to store your data in `Show_data`, so you don't know the type of its contents at compile-time.  Use a strongly-typed collection instead:

   ```
   var final33 = new List<List<Movie>>();
   ....
   for (int i = 0; i < acd.Count(); i++)
   {
       final33.Add(final1.Where(c => c.Id == acd[i]).ToList());
   }
   ```

Then in your view you can iterate over the movie arrays within the model, accessing the properties of the `Movie` type:

```
  @model Project.Models.ViewModels.ShowRecommendationGenreViewModel
    @foreach (var abcc in Model.Show_data)
    {   
       @abcc[0].MovieTitle    
    }
```

Comment: I have been accurately done what you have been said, but now it gives an Error in View :  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<Movies>'
 Kindly help me.

Comment: @MalikBasit My bad. I changed it to use `List` instead of `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

as per your code @abcc seems to be list of list of Movies, so type cast it and iterate through that list to get Movies properties.